# How to calculate mutation rate and mutation sites in a genome using FASTA file?

Tags: sequence-alignment, covid-19, mutations, sars-cov-2, virus

I have 6 viral genome sequences of the same virus and 1 reference sequence in FASTA format.

1. How I can identify mutations and mutation sites in those genomes using FASTA sequences  but how I can do this for FASTA file?
2. And how I can identify the mutation rate for one genome?

**Background** If I've FASTQ file then I'll simply align the reads to the reference and by using variant calling tool I will get the mutate sites

Comment: The mutation rate is impossible to calculate without knowing when the samples diverged. If you have fasta sequences, you can align them and build a tree (I guess beast is the most common tool for viral genomes including time calibration).

Comment: Typically you can align FASTA or FASTQ sequences.  If your variant caller of choice doesn't accept a FASTA and you trust the bases in your FASTA you could mock up the quality scores and make a FASTQ

Answer (score 1):

You can still align a FASTA file with a tool like [bwa mem](https://github.com/lh3/bwa) ( if they are short reads ) or [minimap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2) for long reads and run it through a variant caller like [freebayes](https://github.com/ekg/freebayes). Alternatively, if you have sufficient reads to create an assembly of all of the genomes, or if they already are you can create a MSA of them using a tool like [Cactus](https://github.com/ComparativeGenomicsToolkit/cactus) (as it is built for genomes) or MAFFT if the sequences are short enough and then use your favorite viewer to find variable sites

Comment: I've assembled genome and the genome size is about 30-32k, so I align them and after that, I try to check variable region, It will take a lot of time.

Comment: And how I can calculate mutation rates?

Comment: I don't expect it to take too long to run as MAFFT i-INS-n ( mush slower then Cactus but probably more accurate)  can align my dateset of 208 seq at 200kb  in around 20000 clock hours  (20 hrs with 10 cores ) so 6 should be fine unless they are really gappy.  I am unclear what you mean about mutation rates in this context unless these genomes have established time points